# Inferring non-aliasing solely from restrict pointer parameter declarations

Tags: c, language-lawyer, restrict-qualifier

The C language spec ([n3096](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf), 6.7.3.1/8) gives the following example

> EXAMPLE 2 The function parameter declarations in the following example
>
> ```
> void f(int n, int * restrict p, int * restrict q)
> {
>   while (n-- > 0)
>     *p++ = *q++;
> }
> ```
>
> assert that, during each execution of the function, if an object is accessed through one of the pointer
> parameters, then it is not also accessed through the other. The translator can make this no-aliasing
> inference based on the parameter declarations alone, without analyzing the function body.

How can the translator infer this based on the parameter declarations alone?

For example, allow me to massage this example, preserving the parameter declarations, as follows.

```
int sum;
void f(int n, int * restrict p, int * restrict q)
{
  while (n-- > 0)
    sum += *p++ + *q++;
}
```

I argue it is now permissible for the same object to be accessed through both `p` and `q`, since this object is no longer modified. (Indeed, this seems to be the point of the subsequent EXAMPLE 3 in clause 10.)

My confusion is reinforced in EXAMPLES 5, 6, and 7 (clauses 13, 14, 15). One way to resolve my confusion would be to modify the text in clause 8,

> "... if an object is **modified and** accessed ..."

along with similar changes in the subsequent examples. But to me this seems to change the semantics.

Comment: **How can the translator infer this based on the parameter declarations alone?** Because that's what `restrict` guarantees.

Comment: Aliasing has no effect on your second example, so `restrict` is not necessary and would likely be ignored by the compiler. There's no reason for the function to prohibit aliasing by using `restrict`.

Comment: Clause 4 says that the requirements only apply when the object is modified. This doesn't need to be repeated in clause 8.

Comment: Note also that `restrict` only exists to permit optimizations, it doesn't change the semantics (unless you use it to distinguish `_Generic` functions). See 6.7.3 clause 9.

Comment: @Barmar: That is not what 6.7.3 9 says. It says deleting `restrict` does not change the observable behavior. It does not say that adding `restrict` does not change the observable behavior, so it does not say it does not change the semantics. If you add `restrict` where it does not belong, the behavior may become undefined.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, huh, if removing it can't change the behaviour, then neither can adding it. To say otherwise means you could add it then remove it to get different behaviour from two byte-identical programs.

Comment: @ikegami Adding it could add undefined behavior to some pre-existing calls of the function (from the version of the code before `restrict` was added).

Comment: @ikegami: Removing `restrict` never moves a program from the set of programs with defined behavior into the set of programs without defined behavior. So it never changes the behavior of a program whose behavior was defined. Adding `restrict` can move a program from the former set to the latter. So it can change the behavior of a program whose behavior was defined.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, That may be, yet the spec says the behaviour won't change.

Comment: @ikegami: Re “That may be, yet the spec says the behaviour won't change”: Since you agree it may be—and in fact it is—you can figure out whether the standard or your interpretation of it is wrong. The fact is adding `restrict` can make the behavior not defined by the C standard, and therefore the behavior of programs X and Y that differ only in that Y has `restrict` added may differ. If the behavior of Y is defined, then their behaviors do not differ. That is the sense in which the standard means that removing `restrict` does not change the behavior; it applies only to defined programs…

Comment: … Quite obviously, the standard says nothing about programs with undefined behavior, because it explicitly states that is what its meaning for undefined behavior is: It says nothing about that. So it cannot say that removing `restrict` does or does not change the behavior, as that would be saying something about programs with undefined behavior.

Comment: @ikegami clause 9 (C23 6.7.3.1/9) gives an example where the behavior does change. If the `restrict` qualifiers are removed from `f()` in EXAMPLE 2, then the 2nd call to `f()` from `g()` in clause 9 is perfectly fine. With the `restrict` qualifiers, the 2nd call has UB.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Adding it can make a well-defined program undefined if there were previously callers that passed aliasing pointers.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes. And your point? That is what `restrict` is about. As I wrote, if you add `restrict` where it does not belong, the behavior may become undefined. That is a change in the semantics.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right, my earlier comment was inexact.

Comment: @nknight, Consider `while (n-- > 0) sum += *p++ + *q++;` and emitted code accesses `*p` and `*q` at the _same time_ (think of a parallel processor).  With `int * restrict p, int * restrict q` that never accesses the same memory at the same time.  With `int * p, int * q`, it might access memory at the same time, possibly causing a bus-conflict - so the compiler has to emit other, maybe less efficient code.

Comment: @nknight, As I see it `restrict` does not only apply to modified data.  More like, can I access referenced data without some other pointer also doing the same and getting in the way?  `restrict` lets the compiler know it is OK as there is no overlapping access.

Comment: "I argue it is now permissible for the same object to be accessed through both p and q, since this object is no longer modified."  Well, that's not all that `restrict` does. It also guarantees that neither `p` nor `q` points at `sum`, which is modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a mistake in the example. Instead of saying the declarations assert that “if an object is accessed through one of the pointer parameters,” it should say “if an object is accessed through one of the pointer parameters and is modified during execution of the function.”

We can tell it is a mistake because the formal definition of `restrict`, in 6.7.3.1, does not impose any requirements on an object that is not modified (paragraph 4, “If… and `X` is also modified… then…”), so it is not possible that the declarations assert anything about merely accessing an object (that is accesses that only read the value and do not modify it).

Comment: My example purports to expose a contradiction in the spec. This answer agrees that there is a contradiction. The comments above suggest that others in our community disagree, but I did not follow their argumentation. I am accepting this for now, but will continue to monitor the discussion, and am happy to change my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I argue it is now permissible for the same object to be accessed through both p and q, since this object is no longer modified.

That's not all `restrict` does. It also guarantees that neither `p` nor `q` point at `sum`. Specifically that the only access of a variable's memory location happens through the `restrict` qualified pointer. This enables a bunch of modifications not related to modifying the pointed-at contents. Consider this:

```c
int sum;
void f(int n, int * restrict p, int * restrict q)
{
  int tmp_p = *p;
  int tmp_q = *q;

  external_function();

  if(tmp_p == *p)
  {
    sum = tmp_p + tmp_q;
  }
  printf("%d %d\n", *p, *q);
}
```

`restrict` enables the following optimizations:

- The compiler can assume that `*p` is untouched by the external function so `*p` need not get loaded from memory anew and the `if` statement can be optimized away since it is always true.
- The compiler can assume that writing to `sum` changed neither `*p` nor `*q` so it need not reload them for memory during printing. In fact it can use the values of `tmp_p` and `tmp_q` and print those, in case those variables are already conveniently stored in registers etc.
- The compiler is free to reorder a lot of things in the function, for example it may reorder the access of `tmp_p = *p` until after the external function call. It may however not reorder the `sum = ...` part across the function call, because the external function could be updating `sum`.